# Get latest 4 attachments and then link to their post - WP

Tags: php, wordpress, image, function, attachment

I'd like some assistance modifying this code ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307576/what-is-the-function-got-get-all-the-media-files-wordpress)):

```
    <?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_mime_type' => 'image',
        'numberposts' => 4,
        'post_status' => null,
        'post_parent' => any, // any parent
        ); 
    $attachments = get_posts($args);
    if ($attachments) {
        foreach ($attachments as $post) {
            setup_postdata($post);
            the_attachment_link($post->ID, false);
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Right now, it's getting querying all the image attachments from my WP install and displaying the latest 4 as their thumbnail versions. My problem is that `the_attachment_link` only allows for it to link to either the full-size image or the attachment page of the image. I'd like it to link to the post (and I can guarantee that each image is only attached to 1 post, if that would be an issue/concern).

I've tried using other functions like `wp_get_attachment_image` and `wp_get_attachment_link` but they end up displaying nothing (and no error either). Any help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your solution:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'numberposts' => 4,
    'post_status' => null,
    'post_parent' => 'any', // any parent
);
$attachments = get_posts($args);
if ($attachments) {
    foreach ($attachments as $post) {
        setup_postdata($post);
        ?>
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->post_parent) ?>"><?php echo wp_get_attachment_image($post->ID) ?></a>
    <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Make sure **$post->post_parent** has a value.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Is there a way for me to fill in the `$post->post_parent` bit automatically? I'm displaying these images on the main page outside of any loop so right now, they're linking to the homepage (as you probably would expect)

Comment: If you add attachment/image from a post, post parent will auto fill by post id. If you add attachment/image from media gallery, you have to manually attach with a post.

Comment: Very odd. The images were added via post and not media gallery so I'm not sure why it's resulting in this.

Comment: if your image added via post, you don't have worry about post parent value :). does my example didn't work for images which added via post?

Comment: Yup, pasted your code as is but the permalink leads to the homepage (which is where the code is).

Comment: I have updated my code. there was a missing 'echo' at permalink.

Comment: Hi @Samiul ! Not sure if I should make a new question or not but would you know if it's possible to modify the code you provided and make it specific to a category? (The cat ID is available via `$childcat->cat_ID`)

Comment: Try: `get_category_link($childcat->cat_ID)` instead of `get_permalink($post->post_parent)`

Comment: Thank you for responding! (Should I make a new question for this?) The link is working but the images are still being pulled from all categories and not just the specific one.