# Wordpress - Show a list of all media library images

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a way of outputting a list of all images in the media library? I know, that I could just read the folder on my server, but i don't want all the resized versions.

Comment: Here is the answer for your question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307576/what-is-the-function-got-get-all-the-media-files-wordpress

Comment: Thanks, exactly I was looking for!