# Post image only with a e keyword

Tags: php, css, wordpress, post, gallery

I want to post a gallery formed by a number of images from my site that have a certain keyword. Like from a certain location, or time. I thought to use the caption option or the description option from wordpress. Images will have more keywords, something like: "Location" "Sunset". I tryed to use this [What is the function got get all the media files wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307576/what-is-the-function-got-get-all-the-media-files-wordpress) combined with https://wordpress.org/ideas/topic/functions-to-get-an-attachments-caption-title-alt-description but I cant get them working. Can you help me please. But I am a newbie so can you explain exactly what to write in function.php and what to write in page-name.php

```
LE: <?php $attachment_meta = wp_get_attachment(wp_get_attachement_id()); ?>
    <?php if ($attachement_meta[caption] == 'Ceahlau' ) ?> 
    echo do_shortcode('[gallery columns="4" link="file" ids=" <?php wp_get_attachement_id() ?>"]') 
<?php else: ?> 
<?php endif; ?>
```

This is what I have now in my `page-name.php`

Comment: Show us what your code looks like after using the information from the 2 links mentioned

Comment: '<?php $attachment_meta = wp_get_attachment(wp_get_attachement_id()); ?>
    <?php if ($attachement_meta[caption] == 'Ceahlau' ) ?>
 echo do_shortcode('[gallery columns="4" link="file" ids=" <?php wp_get_attachement_id() ?>"]')
 <?php else: ?>
    <?php endif;  ?>' This is what i have now in my page-name.php

Comment: Can you add it to your post? This makes it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php $attachment_meta = wp_get_attachment(wp_get_attachement_id()); ?>                            
<?php if ($attachement_meta[caption] == 'Ceahlau' ) ?> 
 echo do_shortcode('[gallery columns="4" link="file" ids=" <?php          
 wp_get_attachement_id() ?>"]') 
 <?php else: ?> 
 <?php endif; ?>' 
 This is what i have now in my page-name.php
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This is what i have now in my page-name.php
   <?php

   $args = array(
     'post_type' => 'attachment',
     'numberposts' => -1,
     'post_status' => null,
     'post_parent' => null, // any parent
     'post_mime_type' => 'image'

);  
 $attachments = get_posts($args);
  if ($attachments) {
     $attachment_meta = wp_get_attachment($attachment->ID);
            foreach ($attachments as $post) {
            if ($attachment_meta['caption'] == 'Ceahlau' ){
            setup_postdata($post);
               echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'full' );
               the_attachment_link($post->ID, false);

                            }
                }  
}

?>
```

Comment: Can you please help me with this function I am stack on it