# Get all img and pdf with php

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to get all images from folder with php and link them with another folder where I have pdf files. The names of both are the same.

My code looks like this:

```
    $dir_jpg = "../wp-content/uploads/newspaper/jpg/";
    $dir_pdf = "../wp-content/uploads/newspaper/pdf/";

        $images = glob($dir_jpg."*.*");
        $pdfs = glob($dir_pdf."*.*");

        $array = array_combine($images, $pdfs);

        foreach($array as $image => $pdf){
          echo '<ul>';
            echo '<li>';
              echo '<a href="'.$pdf.'" target="_blank"><img src="'.$image.'" height="100" width="100" /></a>';
            echo '</li>';
          echo '</ul>';
        }
```

I did var_dump to check the array, but it was empty. What could be the reason my code is not working?

**Update**
I store my files in a wordpress folder system, but I didn't upload them through
wordpress media, so there is no records about them in database. I want to avoid it, and upload those files through ftp account and list them with a php code.

**Update 2** On chat with @Gabor Klement we have got to this

```
  $wp_root = wp_upload_dir()['baseurl'];
      $dir_jpg = $wp_root."/newspaper/jpg/";
      $dir_pdf = $wp_root."/newspaper/pdf/";

      $images = glob($dir_jpg."*.*");
      $pdfs = array();

      $imgNum = count($images);

      $list = '<ul>';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $imgNum; $i++) {
            $filename = substr(basename($images[$i]), 0, -4);
            $pdfs[$i] = $dir_pdf.$filename.".pdf";

            if (file_exists($dir_pdf.$filename.".pdf")) {
                $list .= '<li><a href="'.$pdfs[$i].'" target="_blank"><img src="'.$images[$i].'" height="100" width="100" /></a></li>';
            }

        }

        $list .= '</ul>';

        echo $list;
```

but for some reason wordpress is not showing those files. Funy part is that `<img src="<?php echo $dir_jpg ?>/july2012.jpg" />` placed before the $list works

**Update 3**
the only thing that is passing paths to `$images` is `wp_upload_dir()['basedir'];` but then the wordpress creates a path like this `domain.com/home/user/domains/domain/public_html/wp-content/uploads/newspaper/jpg/december2012.jpg` and the image is not found.

Comment: use `*.*` to grab all files

Comment: check that you are providing a filesystem path to glob and not a web accessible path, ex. `/var/www/domain.local/wp-content/uploads/newspaper/jpg/`

Comment: I have updated my code, but still no luck

Comment: in this folder also all images `$dir_pdf` ? or you want to get only Images in both folder?

Comment: @Nawin in `$dir_pdf` I store all my pdf-s and in `$dir_jpg` I store all jpg to keep it more tidy. In both folders the names of the files are the same so I have for ex. july.pdf in `$dir_pdf` and a july.jpg in `$dir_jpg`

Comment: @AlexAndrei for a single img before the php code a path like this works`<img src="../wp-content/uploads/newspaper/jpg/july2012.jpg" />`

Comment: what happens if you don't do `array_combine` and do a `var_dump` on both `$images` and `$pdfs` arrays ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the function got get all the media files wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307576/what-is-the-function-got-get-all-the-media-files-wordpress)
 / As you are obviously in a Wordpress installation, you should use the Worpdress methods for that task. See also: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_media_item

Comment: @AlexAndrei `array(1) { [0]=> array(0) { } }` and changing foreach to `($array as $image)` and it's trying to show an img with src `http://localhost:3000/newspaper-page/Array`

Comment: @feeela even if there are not added through wordpress ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem. I had to use `wp_upload_dir()['basedir']` to pass the path to glob, and then `wp_upload_dir()['baseurl']`to pass the link to src.

Maybe it not the best solution, but it works.

```
  $base_dir = trailingslashit(wp_upload_dir()['basedir']);
  $base_url = wp_upload_dir()['baseurl'];
  $dir_jpg  = '/newspaper/jpg/';
  $dir_pdf  = '/newspaper/pdf/';

  $images = glob($base_dir.$dir_jpg.'*.*');

  foreach($images as $image) {
   $url = $base_url.$dir_jpg.basename($image);

   $filename = substr(basename($image), 0, -4);

   $pdfs = $base_url.$dir_pdf.$filename.".pdf";

   printf('<a href="'.$pdfs.'" target="_blank" class="newspaper-link col-xl-3"><img src="%s" alt="'.$filename.'.pdf"><div class="newspaper-hover"></div></a>', esc_url($url));
        }
```