# Display Random Image from WP Directory

Tags: php, wordpress, image, random

I have used a function

```
 
/*
    Random File Function
    Written By: Qassim Hassan
    Website: wp-time.com
    Twitter: @QQQHZ
*/
 
function Qassim_Random_File($folder_path = null){
 
    if( !empty($folder_path) ){ // if the folder path is not empty
        $files_array = scandir($folder_path);
        $count = count($files_array);
 
        if( $count > 2 ){ // if has files in the folder
            $minus = $count - 1;
            $random = rand(2, $minus);
            $random_file = $files_array[$random]; // random file, result will be for example: image.png
            $file_link = $folder_path . "/" . $random_file; // file link, result will be for example: your-folder-path/image.png
            return '<a href="'.$file_link.'" target="_blank" title="'.$random_file.'"><img src="'.$file_link.'" alt="'.$random_file.'"></a>';
        }
 
        else{
            return "The folder is empty!";
        }
    }
 
    else{
        return "Please enter folder path!";
    }
 
}
 
?>
```

to pull a random image from a specific wordpress directory. I can successfully call up a random image file however it does not display, just displays the image filename and a broken image icon.

The code I am using from the tutorial to display the image is `<?php echo Qassim_Random_File("my-folder-name"); // display random image! ?>`

I am brand new to php as of this week, and a fairly novice coder in general (know some basics) so I really am stumped.  I've fooled with other possible solutions from stack overflow already but this tutorial is the only thing I've been able to get close to working.  Many thanks if anyone can spot the problem!

This is showing up in the HTML inspector:

```html
<div class="elementor-widget-container">
    <h5>call</h5>
    <a href="wp-content/uploads/H-PH-MA-Greyscale/image_2.jpg" target="_blank" title="image_2.jpg">
        <img src="wp-content/uploads/H-PH-MA-Greyscale/image_2.jpg" alt="image_2.jpg">
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code that is generating the link, as this is where the problem will be. All relevant code must be included in the question itself, as external links can break or change over time and make the question unhelpful to future users with the same problem :)

Comment: thanks sorry!  Done.

Comment: First we need to do a bit of debugging to see where the problem is so we can figure out *what* needs to be fixed :) Let's start with what HTML is showing in the element inspector when you inspect the broken image? That will show us if the link is wrong or the image tag is malformed for example.

Comment: Thanks!  Sure.  `"<div class="elementor-widget-container">    <h5>call</h5><a href="wp-content/uploads/H-PH-MA-Greyscale/image_2.jpg" target="_blank" title="image_2.jpg"><img src="wp-content/uploads/H-PH-MA-Greyscale/image_2.jpg" alt="image_2.jpg"></a>  </div>` and all that is displayed on my screen is "call image_2.jpg" and a little broken image icon.

Comment: The problem is with the image URL. we need to add the  domain name to it. But that can depend on your setup. So a few more questions - 1. where is this function added e.g. functions.php? 2. Where is it being called e.g. a template file (if so, which one and where), a widget, shortcode etc? 3. Is your WP site in a folder e.g. example.com/blog?

Comment: Okay, it was rediculously messy with plugins and I couldn't find anything so I did a clean install without the pagebuilder and the problem replicates in the wordpress editor.  1.  The function itself is added to functions.php  2.  The call is added to a php snippets plugin and being done through a shortcode, the site is not in a folder except for / followed by "public_html"

Comment: Hey I figured out a much simpler way to solve this last night in bed, but I don't know if it's problematic.  It allows me to also call extra info about the image too which is nice.  I'm randomly pulling the html for the images from a database I've manually created.  I've ready you shouldn't put images in a db because of their size... but I'm just pulling the html so that should be fine, yes?  Any problem here?  If not I will post the code as an answer.

Comment: You are right, you shouldn't include the images themselves in the database, and storing the path to them is usually the best option.  Your new solution could work, but its a bit of a "workaround" rather than a solution if you are adding the URLs manually. Once you solve the problem with the partial paths (which my answer should do) you could use this code to populate the database instead of having to manually do it - which isn't the most flexible solution :)

Comment: Hmm.  Good point.  I did realize as a result of the workaround idea that whatever I do should probably account for `srcset=`.  Originally I had disabled my wordpress creating different sized images on upload so the directory I'm calling from would have full size images only, but I see now this creates its own issue with no capacity for 'srcset='.  Re the Qassim_Random_Image function,  can you confirm the following is possible:  filter the random call to include images over a certain size only and  2. specific caption and description accompanying the file can also be called

Comment: To get sizes and captions, you'd need to do it through Wordpress functions as that sort of information is stored in the WP database rather than with the files themselves. But that is a very different question, and each question here on Stack Overflow is meant to be about one single thing,  so if you would like to look into that then you would need to post another question. Its also best that you include at least an attempt at the code - otherwise it could get downvoted for lack of research and attempt :) Did the answer below work for this question?

Comment: Yes!  It worked!  :-)  And a very clear answer. I really appreciate your assistance.  Oh, yes I wasn't looking to solve these other questions here, just looking for confirmation that it's possible/makes sense to do so in the context of this code. I will try and figure this out for myself and post a new question if I get stuck. Just trying to be efficient and not chase my tail.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: As for filtering the filenames, you could do that, but it might be better to try using the WP functions instead - it will do a lot of the "heavy lifting" for you. I can't remember what functions you can use off hand to get all the media attachments, but there definitely are some! EDIT: Take a look at this, it might help as a start: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307576/what-is-the-function-got-get-all-the-media-files-wordpress

Comment: Thank you!  Yes this looks promising.  :-)

Comment: Just wanted to let you know with trial and error I was able to piece together something which appears to do exactly what I needed!  :-)  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to replace this line:

```
$file_link = $folder_path . "/" . $random_file;
```

...with this one:

```
 $file_link =  get_site_url(null, $folder_path . "/" . $random_file);
```

**What was the problem?**

`scandir` is returning the physical file path, not the url to the file - we can confirm this is we look at one of the values it returns for `$random_file`, e.g. `wp-content/uploads/H-PH-MA-Greyscale`

This is a relative URL, but we need an absolute URL so that it will work no matter where it is called. We also need to include the **site URL** so that the path to `wp-content` is correct. (Note: [site URL and home URL can be different](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20294/whats-the-difference-between-home-url-and-site-url) - the site URL is the one that always point to the location of the WP files).

Another problem is the trailing slash (or lack of one) on the site URL. `get_site_url` and `get_home_url` do *not* add the trailing slash to the URL, so you need to add it yourself *if* it isn't included in the file path.

**So how do we solve this?**

Using the [`get_site_url` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_site_url/) added the correct path to the WP files, and it also lets us pass it the file path *with our without a preceding slash* as a parameter, and it will add the slash on the path only if it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks simple, if the folder exist and it has more then 2 file (it considers the "." and ".." and files when you use scandir) then you should be able to see something. What's the generated HTML code for that function call?

Be aware that the code you are using builds the file url using the phisical path, that isn't going to work. You should fix this part:

```
if( $count > 2 ){ // if has files in the folder
            $minus = $count - 1;
            $random = rand(2, $minus);
            $random_file = $files_array[$random]; // random file, result will be for example: image.png
            $file_link = get_home_url().$folder_path . "/" . $random_file; // file link, result will be for example: your-folder-path/image.png
            return '<a href="'.$file_link.'" target="_blank" title="'.$random_file.'"><img src="'.$file_link.'" alt="'.$random_file.'"></a>';
        }
```

Notice the **get_home_url()** to build the real URL which is needed for your <img tag src

Comment: Hmm.  Very odd.  Thank you, however when I change this code as you suggested, the same result is produced only with much less consistant speed (often extremely slow).  When I change it back the file is fetched reliably and quickly... but not displayed. The HTML popping up is as follows `<div class="elementor-widget-container">
   <h5>call</h5><a href="wp-content/uploads/H-PH-MA-Greyscale/image_2.jpg" target="_blank" title="image_2.jpg"><img src="wp-content/uploads/H-PH-MA-Greyscale/image_2.jpg" alt="image_2.jpg"></a>  </div>` and all that is displayed on my screen is "call
image_2.jpg"

Comment: are you sure the file exist and the file permission are correctly set? the url is relative so it looks good

Comment: Thanks.  I am sure the file exists as I can access it through my media library or by FTP and see the folder pathway and view the image.  It could be a file permission setting though I guess? Though it is sucessfully entering the folder and fetching the names of random images so wouldn't that suggest it is not a file permission issue?  I don't know anything about this area so perhaps I'm wrong.

Comment: oh wait, is that missing a "/" before wp-content? maybe its just that

Comment: no I tried all variations.  It actually works only *without* a "/" before wp-content.  Again, the issue seems to be in the displaying, not the fetching.  It is finding a random image from the correct directory and it looks like it's even populating into the html correct?  For some reason it's just not showing up.  Since it appears you're confirming the php looks sound, maybe it is something to do with the pagebuilder I am using?

Comment: Just curious if you know whether I would be better off using javascript for this kind of task?  I thought php was better in this case but I don't actually know.